# change permalink from postid to postname without 404

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a wordpress site and i want to change the permalink structure from post id to post name. I already have 100 posts and do not want to break the old links so i want to redirect them without getting error 404.
thanks in advance

Comment: Use `.htaccess` to redirect links. Or you can use `Redirection` plugin to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.htaccess` to redirect links. Or you can use [Redirection Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) to do so.

**Example: `.htaccess` redirect**

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage1.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage1.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage2.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage2.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage3.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage3.html

.

.

.

.

Redirect 301 /oldpage500.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage500.html
```

Use the same code behavior.

Comment: I tried but when I install a plugin like "Redirection" and change permalink to "postname" my old posts get 404 and redirect is not happening.

Comment: Do you have cached enable? If enable, flush the cache first. Also check the redirection URLs are correct.

Comment: How about the cache??

Comment: no i don't have. i tried many plugins as well 301 redirect codes to htaaccess*. site.com/4645/ do not redirect to site.com/postname/!

Comment: `.htaccess` name is wrong here. Please check your file name. This is the code you want to follow `Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html`

Comment: where, is wrong that i din't give you anything! and I want to redirect 500 posts not 1 post!

Comment: You need to create all custom links. Follow the above reference code to do so. See my updated code.